# Second opinion? 2 dead hdds, and 1 hdd that works on another tower

Tags: hard-drive

**Here is my setup:**

- Tower 1

  - Motherboard: ASUS M4A785-M
  - SSD: Kingston SNV425-S2BD
  - OS: Lubuntu 12.04
- Tower 2

  - Motherboard: unknown, very old HP bestbuy bundle
  - OS: Xubuntu 11.10 (Live CD)

**Here are the hdds:**

- HDD 1: Western Digital WD1002FAEX (1TB)
- HDD 2: Seagate Barracuda ST3250820AS (250GB)
- HDD 3: Seagate Barracuda ST3250820AS (250GB)

**The Issue:**

HDD 2 + 3 are both from HP bestbuy bundle towers. HDD 1 is about 1 year old. The SSD in Tower 1 works fine, no troubles with it (it has Lubuntu 12.04) The issue is HDD 1 - 3, which were all find a few days ago. HDD 2 is dead, it clicks when mounting, ect. HDD 1 is effectively broken, I can mount it, but trying to access certain information from it causes it to click and become unrecognized by the system. HDD 3 Will make silent clicking and whirl noises and won't even mount on Tower 1, but HDD 3 works find on Tower 2. (HDD 1 and 2 don't work on Tower 2)

So effectively, HDD 1 - 3 were all working fine until I installed Lubuntu 12.04, after which the 3 HDDs I tried to mount on it ALL stopped working on Tower 1. (I did each drive individually with the SSD, not all at once)

**What is at fault here?**

Is it just a coincidence that 3 of my drives just decided to stop working on the same day? Why does HDD 3 work on Tower 2, but not Tower 1? Why did HDD 1 + 2 only fail after I was working on them with Lubuntu, is Lubuntu the culprit?

**Edit: My Thoughts**

My first reaction is the motherboard in Tower 1... it will "misbehave" some times. It will Post, but it will just stay on the screen with the logo and hot key definitions, or it will not have a message saying how many cores are activated in the CPU (which it normally should)

Should I replace the Motherboard?

**Edit: Results of Disk Fitness Test and Memtest86+**

I only tested HDD 1 and 3 with the Fitness Test, I am pretty sure HDD 2 was shot before I stuck it in Tower 1... I got a Disposition Code = 0x70 from HDD 1, so I RMA'd it on Western Digitals website, and HDD 3 had not problems with it (0x00). It even started to work again in Tower 1! I don't know why it didn't work before.

The memory test reported no problems either for Tower 1, so I don't really know...

Comment: I was thinking a little more about the BIOS hanging issue, have you looked into flashing to a different version?  Also look for leaky capacitors on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that these drives are all having problems separately it very well could be coincidental, I think it would be worth it at this point to test the health of these disks.  This goes without saying, but in situation like this you will want to be sure to back up your data as soon as possible.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities you can use to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

At this point I think it would be premature to replace the motherboard.  One thing to test for would be faulty RAM, with something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the links to those programs, I will probably need them in the future!